# Change the default browser of casperjs to chrome (Change the user-agent string)

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I found out that the default browser of casperjs is safari, because when I tried to access this site https://z1.expertchoice.com using casper and created a screenshot.

How can I change the default browser to chrome?

Comment: Casper doesn't use Chrome, it uses PhantomJS and SlimerJS.  What are you trying to do?  Change the user-agent string?

Comment: sorry, i don't have any idea on what is that user-agent string. what is that by the way?

Comment: When the browser connects to a server, usually one of the request headers is `User-Agent`.  For instance, mine right now is `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36`  That tells the server what browser I'm running.

Comment: is this the right way to change the user agent string? casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5');

Comment: Yes, exactly.  That's correct.

Comment: thank you for introducing me to user-agent string! :)

Comment: Why don't you provide a clear answer, @Brad?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CasperJS doesn't use Safari.  In fact, it can only use PhantomJS and SlimerJS headless browsers for its automation.  Therefore, it cannot work with Chrome either.

You are probably hitting a site that does user-agent detection.  When a browser makes an HTTP request, it typically includes a request header called `User-Agent` which contains information used to identify the browser and other technologies and their versions.  For instance:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36
```

As you have discovered, you can configure your user-agent string in CasperJS using:

```
casper.userAgent('Your User-Agent String Here');
```

There are many [lists online of well known user-agent strings](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php).

Comment: It's best to use `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.41 Safari/535.1` for PhantomJS 1.x, because some sites use user agent sniffing to use specific network technologies or specific JavaScript that is not runnable in PhantomJS with its default user agent string.

Comment: Actually CasperJS or Phantomjs remote debugger is using Safari -- 
https://drupalize.me/blog/201410/using-remote-debugger-casperjs-and-phantomjs

Comment: @andygoestohollywood Don't confuse the Webkit Inspector with Safari.

Answer (score 4):

**`create` parameters**

You can also set it on `create`:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    pageSettings: {
        userAgent: 'mystery browser'
    }
});
```

If you pass an empty string, you get: `User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0`. Which is likely a sensible  prefix to your `userAgent` so that PhantomJS will get better output form websites.

You may also be interested in websites which contain common Firefox user agent strings like this one: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Firefox/ to make it look like you are a real user.